# Not able to mock method which expects interface object

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm using Mockito with Junit version : `4.8.2`
I'm not able to mock methods which expects any interface objects.

For example,

```
public interface If extends Xyz {
}

Class Abc {
    protected List <String> getIPAddress(If x, String n) {
    }
}
```

This is sample test method:

```
@Test
public void testGetIPAddress() {
    Abc mockAbc = mock(Abc.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
    when(mockAbc.getIPAddress(any(Xyz.class), anyString())).thenReturn(new List <String>());
}
```

When I run the above method, I get:
`NullPointerException`

**UPDATES**

Actually I found out that the problem is using `"CALLS_REAL_METHODS"`, when instantiating mocked object. Even if I use

```
when(mockAbc.getIPAddress(any(If.class), anyString())).thenReturn(null);
```

It is throwing NPE. The reason might be it's still calling the real method. 
How do I override calling the real method in this case?

Comment: Which line is throwing NPE ?

Comment: this should'nt even compile...

Comment: `when(mockAbc.getIPAddress(any(Xyz.class), anyString())).thenReturn(new List <String>());`

Comment: Is `List` mentioned a `java.util.List` or another class ?

Comment: please see the update

Comment: Can you provide exact Mockito version and fully qualified name of `mock` method you invoke ?

Comment: For your update question, have you tried it without the "CALL_REAL_METHODS" ? `Abc mockAbc = mock(Abc.class);`

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `getIpAdress` with an `If` not an `Xyz`

Also, `new List <String>()` won't work, as `List` is an interface, use `new ArrayList<String>()` instead:

```
@Test
public void testGetIPAddress() {
    Abc mockAbc = mock(Abc.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
    when(mockAbc.getIPAddress(any(If.class), anyString())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Comment: you have the `NPE` because you are returning `null` in the when. use ` when(mockAbc.getIPAddress(any(If.class), anyString())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>());` and you can call `mockAbc.getIPAddress(null, null).toString();` without throwing an NPE